# Get alt attribute of images inside a Contenteditable div and replace the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unicode, contenteditable

I've implemented small web chat application and used `smileys` in it.
I've made my div `contenteditable="plaintext-only"` and adding both text and smileys images to that div.
whenever user clicks on smileys, an `image with unicode character as alt` will bind to the contenteditable div and he can also type text in it.
So, Finally after clicking the send button, I need to get the whole content in div and `replace the images with unicodes in the alt` and get the plain text as text itself and send message.

My smileys binding code :

```
$("span.emo", container).click(function () {
   debugger;
   var toSlice = $(this).attr("data-emoji").split('-'); // get unicode Character
   var preview = emojione.toImage(toSlice[1]); // unicode to image conversion
   $('.mydiv').html($('.mydiv').html() + preview); // append image to the div
});
```

My div's Content after adding images and text

```
   <div id="mydiv" contenteditable="plaintext-only" class="mydiv" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #ccc; margin-bottom: 100px">
     <img class="emojione" alt="" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/png/1F478.png?v=1.2.4"><img class="emojione" alt="" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/png/1F63A.png?v=1.2.4">
     <img class="emojione" alt="" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/png/1F638.png?v=1.2.4"><img class="emojione" alt="" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/png/1F63D.png?v=1.2.4">
     <img class="emojione" alt="" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/png/1F63C.png?v=1.2.4"><img class="emojione" alt="" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/png/1F640.png?v=1.2.4">&nbsp;Hello Users<br>
   </div>
```

My Send Button Code

```
function Send() {
   debugger;
   //var allimgs = $('.mydiv').find('.emojione');
   var alldata = $('.mydiv').html(); // getting all html data but dont know how to loop through every element
   var childrendata = $(".mydiv").children(); // here I'm not getting the text, only getting the images as array
   var contenteditable = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]'),
                text = contenteditable.textContent; // here also I'm getting only text
}
```

My question is :

I need to get the data and loop through every element and replace all images with unicodes. My final data should be like :  Hello Users

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: So what's the problem? `$('img').attr('alt')`. Also `data` attribute can be accessed via it's object `$(selector).data('emoji')`

Comment: I need to get the data and loop through every element and replace all images with unicodes.
My data should be like :  Hello Users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over `children()` and use **[`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)** to replace the `img` by its `alt` attribute.

```
function Send() {
    $('.mydiv').children('.emojione').each(function () {
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).prop('alt'))
    });
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6tjLrwpg/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add this little snippet for a demo transformation. It replaces images with their alt tag, pretty straight forward.

```js
/* Added snippet */
window.transform = function() {
    $('.emojione').each(function () {  // for each emoji
        var unicode = $(this).attr('alt');  // grab attribute 'alt'
        this.outerHTML = unicode;  //  set the images entire html as the alt tag instead
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" contenteditable="plaintext-only" class="mydiv" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #ccc; margin-bottom: 50px">
    <img class="emojione" alt="" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/png/1F478.png?v=1.2.4">
    <img class="emojione" alt="" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/png/1F63A.png?v=1.2.4">
    <img class="emojione" alt="" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/png/1F638.png?v=1.2.4">
    <img class="emojione" alt="" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/png/1F63D.png?v=1.2.4">
    <img class="emojione" alt="" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/png/1F63C.png?v=1.2.4">
    <img class="emojione" alt="" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/png/1F640.png?v=1.2.4">&nbsp;Hello Users
</div>
<!-- Added Button -->
<button onclick="transform()">Transform!</button>
```